# How to update google calendar event datetime using API V3

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

I can successfully update the title of the events using Google API V3, but once I include the datetime, I get internal server error. Here's the snippet of my code:

```
$event = $service->events->get($calendar_id,$event_id);
$event->setSummary($notes);
$service->events->update($calendar_id,$event->getId(),$event);
```

The above code works well since I'm only updating the title. I'm struggling with the code below:

```
$event = $service->events->get($calendar_id,$event_id);
$event->setSummary($notes);

$start = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
$start->setDateTime('2014-07-22T20:00:00+08:00');  
$event->setStart($start);
$end = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
$end->setDateTime('2014-07-22T21:00:00+08:00');  
$event->setEnd($end);

$service->events->update($calendar_id,$event->getId(),$event);
```

I'm not sure if I have the correct format for the datetime. Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: It works now. Just had a typo in my variable.

Answer (score 1):

// Cambio de fecha de evento

```
$end = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
$end->setDateTime('2021-09-01T14:00:00');
$end->setTimeZone('America/Mexico_City');
$event->setEnd($end);

$Start = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
$Start->setDateTime('2021-09-01T12:00:00');
$Start->setTimeZone('America/Mexico_City');
$event->setStart($Start);

$updatedEvent = $service->events->update(CalendarID, $event->getId(), $event);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do $event->setEnd($end); instead of $event->setStart($end);

Comment: Corrected it already. still getting internal server error @luc